# Using remote data in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone ELI5 how to grab json data via GET in Angular, and have it available to a controller -

I'm currently doing this:

```
app.factory('dataRepo', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
           return $http.get('/data.json');
        }
     };
 });

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, _, dataRepo) {

    dataRepo.getData().success(function(d) {
        $scope.data= d; 
        console.log($scope.data)
    });
    console.log($scope.data);
    /* more stuff in here using $scope.data
});
```

The first `console.log` call logs the data, the second [outside the success function] logs undefined, and writes prior to the other call.

How do I get the data before the app kicks off, or how do I defer the remainder of the code until `$scope.data is populated?? I've looked at promises, and can get the result I need doing what I know is a really dodgy implementation and I don't want to persist with it

Comment: you are seeing expected behavior of all ajax. This is not exclusive to angular. AJAX is asynchronous. What is higher level problem? Show more code you have problems with

Answer (score 0):

U can register a watcher on data and get notified about every change. If data is an array, the third parameter is a boolean watching objects more deeply.

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {

}, /*true*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the $http.get call is asynchronous, aka the script continues without calling the callback directly. Therefore the second call to console.log() is executed first and $scope.data is still undefined at this point. Later when the http request is completed the function block inside success() is executed and $scope.data becomes populated.

Although promises make handeling with asynchronous code much easier it doesn't make it synchronous like you'll generally code on the backend.

A solution could be to place the logic which requires the data inside the success() callback.

If you need the data outside the mainCtrl you can use the $watch method like @angabriel suggested, but this code needs to handle de data in all cases. 1: undefined, 2: populated. 
3: changed again?

If you're using angular routes to create the controller (and not `ng-controller="mainCtrl"`)
You can use the resolve property to delay the controller/view until the data is loaded [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741359/angularjs-dependency-injection-in-resolve)